# Twitter Bootstrap elements spill-over page edge at 1200 wide and above

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I'm new to Twitter Bootstrap and struggling to understand some of the responsive behaviour / styling. I have searched around but either I'm poorly phrasing my questions, this is not a common problem, or I'm just blind to the obvious.

I'm using the grid framework and when my document width is at or just over 1200px I see some content spilling over the left edge of the screen. The spill-over happens as I go from 1199 to 1200. None of the layouts below 1200 have the same problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/xBD9k/ - adjust the output window until the document width reads 1200

The structure of the page is as follows (all non-fluid):

```
container
 row
  span12
   row
    span12
```

As far as I can tell there is no issue with nesting rows and span12s (I have a good reason, I promise) as the positive and negative left-margins seem to cancel each other out to prevent progressive indentation.

The container's explicit width is 1170px with margin: auto on both sides. However the first row's rendered width is 1200px with margin-left: -30px, so it always hangs over the edge. However the row has no styles that explicitly give it that width, and the span12 within it has an explicit width of 1170 margin-left of 30.

I can make things right again by disabling styles within Chrome's developer tools, but I know I shouldn't have to go editing the Bootstrap CSS to make this happy.

Can anyone tell me why the 1200px and above styles would be spilling over the edge like this? Once I expand the width to 1220px or so everything fits nicely back on the page.

Comment: Can you replicate it in a JsFiddle?

Comment: @jmeas yes I can - edited question

Comment: If I add a background color to your container, the text is inside the container with a document width of 1200px. Can you clarify which "edge" the content is spilling over?

Comment: Perhaps unsurprisingly, working through the JS Fiddle has shown me where my misunderstanding lay. I was using background-color to identify areas in my app. I was styling the row when I should have been styling the span12. The row colour made it look like the content was falling off the screen. Thanks for the assistance in getting here

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're confusing the rows with the spans. A row with a document width of 1200 will have the same width even if you nest it. The thing you have to track is your spans.

```
row - 1200px width
  span12 - 1170px width
    row - 1200px width
      span12 - 1170px width
```

The reason being that the span12 has a hard coded width of 1170px and the row resets the left margin with -30px

This part of the css code may help explain

```
@media (min-width:1200px) {
    .row {
        margin-left: -30px;
        *zoom: 1;
    }

    .container {
        width: 1170px;
    }

    .span12 {
        width: 1170px;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the input, I think this would have got me to where I needed to be if I hadn't figured it out before you answer. The problem is I was styling the background-color of my rows, not my spans. Everything was nested fine but it looked like my span12 was pushing off the page - this was actually just the negative margin of the row coming into play

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I was styling the background-color of my rows, not my spans. Everything was nested fine but it looked like my span12 was pushing off the page - this was actually just the negative margin of the row coming into play